# Is a string higher than another string in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Workout if a string holding a version number is higher than another string holding a version number in Python 3.

This is what I have tried:

```
request_version = "1.10.1"
current_version = "1.11"
if Decimal(request_version) > Decimal(current_version):
    pass
```

However, I get this error, why?

```
InvalidOperation at /api/version/
[<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

Comment: Youe example works for me

Comment: its actually working for me...

Comment: Nope, works fine: https://repl.it/BteN. Are you sure you're not trying to take a patch release (e.g. `1.2.3`) or something? Also, note that releases don't compare numerically - `1.2` is less recent than `1.11`, even though it's a larger number, for example.

Comment: sorry yes, it's 1.10.1

Comment: I'll update OP now to reflect this.

Comment: Well then: 1. The answer is obvious (*"why?"* - because `1.10.1` isn't a valid number); and: 2. You're still going to hit the problem that comparing them as numbers is precisely the wrong way to do this.

Comment: Version strings are not decimal numbers! Use functions specialised in comparing version strings.

Comment: Could you help and provide an answer on how I could compare these?

Comment: In terms of how to correctly compare version numbers, see e.g. http://semver.org/. In terms of implementation, write your own homework!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert your version string to a float, which fails because `1.2.3` is not a valid float.

What you probably want for this kind of things is the [packaging](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/) package, which implements the [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) version semantics (among other niceties):

```
>>> from packaging.version import parse
>>> request_version = parse("1.10.1")
>>> current_version = parse("1.11")
>>> request_version > current_version
False
>>> request_version < current_version
True
```

This `parse` will create a `Version` object, which allows comparison between versions

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `LooseVersion` from `distutils.version`:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion as V

current = V('1.10.1')
request_version = V('1.11')

if current < request_version:
    print("Yay.")
```